# Manter os campos preenchidos no modo edição

Tags: jquery

Colegas.

Tenho um código, que não é de minha autoria, do qual na hora de cadastrar o usuário clica em um botão **Adicionar mais tamanhos** e mais campos aparecem. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui tudo certo, os tamanhos e estoques vão para a base de dados. O problema está na hora de editar. Gostaria que esses campos já aparecessem "abertos" para que eu possa incluir as informações que virão do banco de dados. Vejam o código:

```
<table border="0">  
<tr class='linhas'>
    <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="Tamanho[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Tamanho"></td>
    <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="Estoque[]" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Estoque"></td>
    <td  style="padding: 5px"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"><button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-primary" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais tamanhos</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Dessa forma não tem como responder a sua pergunta, dê mais detalhes. Qual linguagem você está utilizando para fazer a conexão com o banco? Você já tem as informações na view? Qual o formato que está vindo?

Comment: Olá Junior. O problema está no jquery e não no PHP ou Mysql. Preciso que na hora de editar, apareça a quantidade de campos referentes a quantidade de informações cadastradas baseadas no código do post.

Comment: Sim, mas como você vai obter quantos itens estão cadastrados e quais as devidas informações? Isso terá que vir do MySQL e do PHP não? Você já tá trazendo?

Comment: Isso... estou sim. Consigo trazer as informações do banco de dados, todos os campos do formulário já estão preenchidos com as informações, só faltam esses...

Comment: Mas a gente precisa saber como tá vindo essa informação, qual o nome da variável? qual a estrutura dos dados? tem como você "printar" o valor dessa variável?

Comment: Olá Junior. Consegui trazer. Fiz dentro do laço do PHP mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver trazendo do PHP mesmo.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE IDProdutos = '".$idProdutos."';");
     $visualizar = "";

    while($jmTamanhos = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){  
        if($jmTamanhos->Tamanho != ""){
           $visualizar .=  "<tr class='linhas'>
                            <td  style=\"padding: 5px\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"Tamanho[]\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Tamanho\" value='".$jmTamanhos->Tamanho."'></td>
                            <td  style=\"padding: 5px\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"Estoque[]\" class=\"form-control pull-left\" placeholder=\"Estoque\" value='".$jmTamanhos->Estoque."'></td>
                            <td  style=\"padding: 5px\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"removerCampo btn btn-danger\" title=\"Remover linha\"><i class=\"fa fa-minus-square\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> Remover</button></td>
                        </tr>";      
        }
     }
     return $visualizar;     
 }
```